# Remove auto Date Picker in chrome when using tag helpers in Asp.Net MVC core 2.2

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Using the following tag helper within my asp.net core 2.2 app, Chrome shows a html5 date picker (as shown).

```
    <div class="col-md-6 input-group-sm">
        <label asp-for="Dob"></label>
        <input asp-for="Dob" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Dob" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

Model property for DOB is -

```
public DateTime? Dob { get; set; }
```

What is generated in chrome -

[image]

This does not occur within Internet Explorer and i can see that it is due to chrome adding type="datetime-local" to the html.

**Question**

Is there a way to remove this auto generated datepicker so that i can use an alternative?

Comment: There's no supported browser called `Internet Explorer` any more. The type is added by ASP.NET Core, not the browser. You can add your own `type`. You can use `date` to display a date picker or `datetime-local` for a field that accepts a time component too. Check the [input types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) to see which is the best for your case

Comment: As for the UI, different browsers behave differently. `This does not occur within Internet Explorer` - that's a bug in IE. Since IE is no longer supported, this won't be fixed. There's nothing wrong with Chrome's behavior and given that even Edge is switching to the Chromium engine, this UI is probably the most common one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `type="text"` to remove default `type="datetime-local"`.

```
<input type="text" asp-for="Dob" class="form-control"/>
```